# How can I run local php files in android tablet?

Tags: php, android, cordova, jetty

I have a PHP project which contains MySQL database and I want to run it on android tablet without any server, so how can I do this?

Comment: thnx mr.Chathuranga for edit my question in case of wrong format. bt can tell me the answer of question of mine?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, and this is only a cli interpreter, so if you're looking for something like WAMP for android, I believe you're out of luck, but if you're rooted, and want to just run some small scripts from the command line, these guys have a package:

http://phpforandroid.net/

Comment: +1 for the good new trick but I think this one is not that much useful in this context

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want then, I assume you're looking for a server as well to run on the android device?